# How to save SpaceBoundaries in BIM-Add-on?

Tags: add-on

I generated an IfcSpace and added SpaceBoundaries (2ndLevel if that is important) but when I open the ifc-file again I can never see them.

I can select the IfcSpace and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> but surely there is a way to see them from the moment where I open the file?

Also, when I edit their shape (for example around a door/if there is a wall on the back and so on) the original shape is always saved, not the edited one. As well as the face orientation of the Normal, which is (most of the times) flipped again when I re-open the file.

I use Blender 3.6 and the BIM-Add-on v0.0.231104

Comment: That addon is a third-party addon, not part of Blender so questions about it are off-topic here. You'll have to ask the addon author(s).

Comment: @JohnEason As discussed in these two meta posts [1](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267),[2](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3043) questions about third party addons can be answered here, if anyone happens to know the answer. I don't think there are any active exports about BlenderBim here though, and I know it only very superficially. Maybe it is best to ask over at the dedicated community at https://osarch.org

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Fair enough. I'm not familiar with that addon but it sounded from this particular question as if it related more to the external side of the IFC toolkit rather than to Blender itself.

Comment: Indeed it is an addon extensive enough that it is almost an entire thing of its own. It also alters Blender significantly, but I think we could still accept questions about it here eventually. At the moment I haven't seen anyone versed enough to be able to help meaningfully.

Comment: thanks for your help, anyways! I already asked on osarch as well but I thought I might ask more people - since maybe different people know different approaches :) but I'm sure I'll have more Blender related questions in the fututre too !